Pinging a website from a cloud server in private network on hetzner over opnsense router not working
I am a newbie in nategateway and networking
I want to make a cloud server in a private network accessible to the internet through opnsense. I am using hetzner cloud provider
I tried to ping google ip (142.250.105.139) but I got error
network not reachable

I tried to ping www.google.com but I got this error
www.google.com temporary error in name resolution

but I can ping the opnsense from the cloud server
Network Configuration
opnsense server: router / 10.0.0.2
client server: 10.0.0.3
Hetzner Network: nat-network / 10.0.0.0/16
Hetzner subnet: 10.0.0.0/24
Hetzner gateway: 10.0.0.1

Advanced Outbound NAT
Interface: WAN
  Address Family: IPv4
  Protocol: any
  Source: WAN Address
  Destination: any
Translation
  Address: WAN Address

There is no default LAN rule so I created one.
Note. I used opt1 as LAN
  Action: Pass
  Interface: LAN
  Address Family: IPv4
  Protocol: TCP
  Source: any
  Destination: LAN Network

static route
Destination network: 10.0.0.0/16
Gateway: 10.0.0.1

WAN Rule
Action: Block
Interface: WAN
Address Family: IPv4+IPv6
Protocol: TCP/UDP
Source: any
Destination: This firewall (self)
Destination Port Range: From "HTTP (80)" to "HTTPS (443)"

I am following this tutorial
https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/how-to-route-cloudserver-over-private-network-using-pfsense-and-hcnetworks
